# Migrating a DHCP Database From Domain Member to Standalone Server

Tags: dhcp, migration

I need to migrate a DHCP database (the whole thing) from a server that is a domain member to a server that is a standalone server. Please don't ask me why, it is a necessary evil. :) There are a few hundred leases and about 20 scopes. I plan to shut down the service in the middle of the night, export the database, import it on the new server, change the DHCP relay on the necessary switches and call it a night.

When I export the database and import it on the new server during a test run, it tells me that I need to authorize the server. Now, obviously I can't do that since this is a standalone server. There isn't even the "authorize" option in the menu. I'd appreciate any insight into this issue. I'm going from Server 2003 R2 to 2008 x86.

Comment: Are you also migrating the following registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DHCPServer\Configuration

Comment: @Wesley I'm not. There is nothing in any microsoft doc that I have read that says to do this. Is there a reason to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that a standalone Windows DHCP server will not start if it's on the same subnet as an existing and authorized DHCP server. The error message is rather unhelpful, but after the initial server had the DHCP service stopped on it and 5ish minutes had gone by, the new server started with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard of authorizing a DHCP server but never a scope. Are you sure it's not asking you to activate the scope?

Comment: Yes, late-night typo.

Comment: Ouch. Who gave me the drive by downvote?